# How to generate list of consecutive integers with differents combinations?

Tags: elixir, permutation

I would like to generate all possible lists (with length 5) of integers from 1 to 6 (1,2,3,4,5,6) where there are at least 4 integers in sequential order.

For example:

```
[6,1,2,3,4] -> 1,2,3,4 are in sequential order 

[1,3,4,5,6] -> 3,4,5,6 are in sequential order 

[2,3,4,5,1] -> 2,3,4,5 are in sequential order

[1,2,3,4,5] -> 1,2,3,4 and 2,3,4,5 are in sequential order
```

each digit can appear in the list only once

Please help with this task. How could it be solved?

at the moment i tried such options:

```
Enum.map(1..6, fn a -> [a, b, c, d] = Enum.to_list(a..6) |> Enum.shuffle() |> Enum.take(4) |> Enum.sort() end )
```

```
Enum.map(0..2, fn a -> [x,y,z,w] = [a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4]  end )
```

```
Enum.map(1..3, fn a -> Enum.to_list(a..6) end)
```

but all options do not work correctly

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: added the question, sorry I didn't show what I had already done

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5]` more than exactly four are in sequential order in this example. Is that acceptable? Where does the question come from?

Comment: yes, it is okey if more that one in sequential order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a must be a better way to do this, but this seems to work. I used the [Rosetta Code permutations implementation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Elixir) and added an outer layer that [filters](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) the final results based on the sequential conditions you specified.

```rb
defmodule Example do
  def run() do
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    for x <- list,
        [a, b, c, d, e] <- permute(list -- [x]),
        (a == b - 1 && b == c - 1 && c == d - 1) ||
          (b == c - 1 && c == d - 1 && d == e - 1) do
      [a, b, c, d, e]
    end
  end

  def permute([]), do: [[]]

  def permute(list) do
    for x <- list, y <- permute(list -- [x]), do: [x | y]
  end
end
```

Result:

```rb
iex> Example.run
[
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 2],
  [6, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 1],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
  [6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
  [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
]
```